# Strange PHP CURL issue

Tags: php, curl, vk

My main target is to get videos from russian social network Vkontakte. Working with following https://github.com/sjevs/SJevsLib/ scripts. Decided to test this script like that:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
include 'vk.php';
$login = "..."; //Vkontakte login here
$password = "..."; //pass
$phoneLast4Digits = "..."; //digits
$vk = new Vk($login, $password, $phoneLast4Digits);

// Get array of the movies
$videos = $vk->search('The Avatar');
var_dump($videos);
// get iframe code for any movie from array
$html = $vk->play($videos[0]['id1'], $videos[0]['id2']);

echo $html;
```

var_dump returned nothing. When I took a close look into grabber.php I see that it uses tor network to change identity. I'm using shared server and I have no tor software installed. Maybe problem occured because of tor? How can I get it work on shared cpanel server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable TOR by commenting out following lines in Grabber.php

```
CURLOPT_PROXY => $this->torSettings['ip'].':'.$this->torSettings['port'],
CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5,
```

Comment: Or find any Tor node and use it in `$torSettings`

Comment: Well I did it. Same thing! it doesn't return any array